# How to add more fields in Iris RSSiDemo packet

Tags: nesc

Can any one tell me how to increase packet size  using IRIS mote.
I am pasting my Header file i hav added nodeid and counter but it is not appearing in the packet..Any help will be great full
RssiDemoMessages.h

Comment: It would be helpful if you could actually post your code. At the moment only header file name is visible...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following line on your Makefile

```
CFLAGS += -DTOSH_DATA_LENGTH=50
```

Where 50 is the number of bytes. Keep in mind that packet loss will increase as the number of bytes increases as well.